# Electron: Quicker "Loading Screen" Window

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an Electron application that I am trying to optimize the startup as much as I can.  My main file is:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog } = require("electron")
const path = require("path")
const url = require("url")

let mainWindow = null
let loadingScreen = null
    
const createLoadingScreen = () => {
  loadingScreen = new BrowserWindow({
    useContentSize: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 350,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
  })

  loadingScreen.setResizable(false)

  const startURL = url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "loading.html"),
    protocol: "file:",
    slashes: true,
  })

  loadingScreen.loadURL(startURL)
  loadingScreen.on("closed", () => (loadingScreen = null))

  loadingScreen.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
    loadingScreen.show()
  })
}

createMainWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    useContentSize: true,
    width: 1400,
    minWidth: 1200,
    height: 870,
    minHeight: 870,
    title: "MyApp",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      enableWebSQL: false,
    },
    show: false,
  })

  mainWindow.setMenu(null)

  const startUrl =
    process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL ||
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    })

  mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl)

  mainWindow.on("ready-to-show", () => {
    /// when the content has loaded, hide the loading screen and show the main window
    if (loadingScreen) {
      loadingScreen.close()
    }
    mainWindow.show()
  })
}

app.once("ready", () => {
  createLoadingScreen()
  createMainWindow()
})

app.on("window-all-closed", () => app.quit())

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) createMainWindow()
})
```

The application startup is the following times:

```
App Ready: 0.057 seconds
Loading Screen Display: 2.437 seconds
Main Screen Display: 3.466 seconds
```

As you can see Electron is "Ready" at 0.057 seconds, however, it takes nearly 2.5 seconds to create my super simple (single image) HTML splash page, and then another second for the main application to load.

My desire is to find a way to at minimum get my splash screen up ASAP so that the user at least knows that the application is loading - it currently just sits there prompting the user to click the icon again.

Is there any tricks to get the initial page to be created in less than 2.5 seconds?

I am running the following system:

```
Window 10 Pro (Build 18363)
32GB RAM
Intel Xeon W-2145 CPU @ 3.7Ghz (16 CPUs)
NVIDIA Quadro P2200
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you come up with a solution? Having kinda the same problem

Comment: @tommygun Unfortunately no.  It's just one of those "is what it is" situations.  VSCode has very quick loading times and I spent some time researching how they achieved this but didn't make much progress.  In the end, we ended up converting the Electron application to an internal Web App instead to ease our deployment.